# C++ programming and compiling for unexperience programmers

Tags: c++, docker, visual-studio-code, compilation

I have came to the new company where at the testing department is a lot of non-programmers. The issues is that the C++ programming experience are needed to write a specific test case (there are more test managers). They have learn some basics and use some standard stuff. Now they push me into the project where we must make their life's easier in several stages.

One of the tasks in the first stage will be to get rid of all terminal commands, **so there must be some kind "one click compiling/build" solution available**, what is little hard to achieve especially in case when they use both windows and linux approach on the test-benches. I have overview several options:

- to install MinGW (or GCC) for compiling (installing on computer needed) + batch files (the problem here is that installing is needed - possibility to compile at "save" button
- or docker connection with text-editor (visual studio code) to "remote compile" (https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/develop-remote-host)

The question is if there is any other option or approach that can be used in such case? Or which option will be choosen by you? Another stage for them will be also GUI editor for test cases, but this will be a loooong stage. In the first stage we are searching some "between" stage to make there life easier (standard lib + easy compiling solution).

Thanks!

Comment: Use something like Jenkins to compile and package the artifacts so they can just be downloaded and unzipped for use.

Comment: The question I have is why on earth you would want people writing C++ test cases who are not experienced in C++. In my experience, even intermediate engineers mess this up. If it were me, I'd push the test work out to Python, add hooks to C++ as necessary, and write good C++ test cases yourself for the glue.

Comment: As far as CI build environments go, Jenkins is pretty popular. A slightly more modernized option is GitLab, which is more of a suite of connected systems with a more friendly interface.

Comment: Poor you, I have some Java background but my brain get pain while moving to C++ :/

Comment: paddy .. is not everything my decision. Problem is that they don't use GIT at this time (they use some old version of PTC). It is plan to introduce that in the future, but I must be careful at which level and how. For "unexperience" people I am most aiming to the direction of the web GUI and everything else will be generated in the background. They are already in this mess several years, so some between phase I need that I gain more time for "real" solution.